# S3 select - How can I query by non-standard timestamp comparison

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-s3-select

I'm using a S3 bucket where the data is organized into files by an ID & year/month - meaning one file per ID & month.
In each (csv.gz) file each record has a timestamp in the format: `YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` (note the missing `T`).

Now, when querying the data I want to support datetime granularity down to seconds so naturally it's desired to filter the data in S3 already prior to managing the data in Python.

I can't however find any method to do this.
The function `TO_TIMESTAMP` doesn't support a user provided format (expects a `T` date/time separator) and combining SUBSTRING and CAST (`CAST(SUBSTRING(my_timestamp_column, 1, 10) AS TIMESTAMP)`) yields a `The query cannot be evaluated` error.

Is there any way around this?
The documentation states that the function `TO_TIMESTAMP` is "the inverse operation of TO_STRING" which is not quite true as the latter supports a `time_format_pattern`.

Answer (score 2):

I think I had to solve the same or similar problem.  As you said, the documentation (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/s3-glacier-select-sql-reference-date.html#s3-glacier-select-sql-reference-to-timestamp) states that the function `TO_TIMESTAMP` is the inverse operation of `TO_STRING`.  But the documentation to me was misleading, because it does not make clear that the `TO_TIMESTAMP` function does support `time_format_pattern` as a second argument.  The documentation shows that it only takes one argument, but it can in fact take two.

I was able to convert a non-standard timestamp `20190101T050000.000Z` from type string to timestamp like so:

```
aws s3api select-object-content --bucket foo_bucket --key foo.json.gz --expression "SELECT * FROM s3object s WHERE TO_TIMESTAMP(s.\"timestamp\", 'yMMdd''T''Hmmss.SSS''Z''') < TO_TIMESTAMP('20190101T050000.000Z', 'yMMdd''T''Hmmss.SSS''Z''')" --expression-type 'SQL' --input-serialization '{ "CompressionType": "GZIP","JSON": {"Type": "DOCUMENT"}}' --output-serialization '{"JSON": {"RecordDelimiter": "\n"}}' /dev/shm/foo.json
```

Hope that helps somebody out.

Answer (score 0):

Having same issue over here, I went an step over and change my csv file to grant date field with require format by timestamp date type in S3 Select.The requiere format is described here [S3 data types](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/s3-glacier-select-sql-reference-data-types.html)

So first, in order to response the question, based on S3 Select documentation, I think is not possible to work with a date without `T` at the end. By the time you correct that, you will be able to work with `CAST` function. Next is what I do:

`select * from s3object as s where CAST('2020-01-01T' AS TIMESTAMP) < CAST('2021-01-01T' AS TIMESTAMP)`

That works just okay, however as you can see, I'm not passing `s."Date"` which is the field header in my csv file due to following error:

*Attempt to convert from one data type to another failed at line 1, column 39: cast from STRING to TIMESTAMP.*

I hope have been help a little bit, and hope someone can help with this error.